# arranging and printing numpy arrays values side by side

Tags: python, numpy

i am facing problem on printing the values obtained from below arrays values side by side.Actually i have two arrays like

```
            x=np.arange(1.0,10.0,0.5)
            y=np.arange(1.0,10.0,0.4)
```

and i want to print x and y values like as follows

```
    x        y

   1.0      1.0
   1.5      1.4
   2.0      1.8   
   2.5      2.2
   3.0      2.6
   ...      ...
```

i tried like    import numpy as np
x=np.arange(1.0,10.0,0.5)
y=np.arange(1.0,10.0,0.4)
print(x,y)

but it doesnot print what i want can anybody help me on carrying this work out.Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print two arrays side by side using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443888/print-two-arrays-side-by-side-using-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through elements of both arrays by using zip and then print out the elements.

```python
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(1.0,10.0,0.5)
y=np.arange(1.0,10.0,0.4)

print("x   y")
for a,b in zip(x,y):
    print(a,b)
```

However, this will only work if both arrays are the same size. If the arrays are not the same size you may want to look into itertools.zip_longest https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest.